# Struts2 pass url as a string

Tags: javascript, struts2

I'm using javascript function to submit form, and in the javascript function, I'd specify `form.action= "Struts2 url goes here";`

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
var form = document.forms['myForm'];
if (form != null) {
    var backURL = "ActionB!someMethodB.action?Bparam1=somevalue&Bparam2=somevalue";
    form.action="ActionA!someMethodA.action?Aparam1=somevalue&Aparam2=" + backURL;
    form.submit();
}
```

The problem is that in the action method `someMethodA`, the value for `Aparam2` is always cut off by the first ampersand in `backURL`.

I tried to enclose `backURL` with quotes like this `form.action="ActionA!someMethodA.action?Aparam1=somevalue&Aparam2='" + backURL + "'";` but it did not work. It kind of makes me feel like that the value of `backURL` is not treated as a whole but parsed as well.

I would like to know if there's a way to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a parameter in the url which contains special characters they should be urlencoded.

```
var backURL = encodeURIComponent("ActionB!someMethodB.action?Bparam1=somevalue&amp;Bparam2=somevalue");
```

Also, a hardcoded value for URL could be built on server with [`s:url`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/url.html) tag.

```
var backURL = encodeURIComponent('<s:url action="ActionB" method="someMethodB"><s:param name="Bparam1" value="somevalue"/><s:param name="Bparam2" value="somevalue"/></s:url>');
```

In this case by default `&` is escaped to `&amp;` but escaped value is used normally with the browser.

Comment: helped alot. Thank you.